# On the algorithm of transforming image histogram into linear shape

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am a beginner in opencv and I am using python. I encountered a difficulty, which is to define the histogram of a grayscale image into a linear shape, or how many pixels there are for each grayscale value, like the following:
My goal is to regulate the histogram of the grayscale image on the left into the shape on the right:

[image]

I have no ideas, I would like to ask you all, thank you for your answers

Comment: Have a read here... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! What do you mean by ":My goal is to regulate the histogram of the grayscale image on the left into the shape on the right"? The histogram of the image (a) should look similar to the histogram (b)? This might be useful - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching